# Initializing default values in a struct

Tags: c++

If I needed to initialize only a few select values of a C++ struct, would this be correct:

```
struct foo {
    foo() : a(true), b(true) {}
    bool a;
    bool b;
    bool c;
 } bar;
```

Am I correct to assume I would end up with one `struct` item called `bar` with elements `bar.a = true`, `bar.b = true` and an undefined `bar.c`?

Comment: the bar is just a renaming, if you are using c++ you don't need to do things this way

Comment: @aaronman no, `bar` is a variable.

Comment: @aaronman I think you're confusing this with `typedef struct foo {} bar;`.

Comment: So, if `bar` is the struct, what's `foo`?  Is this the same as defining a `foo` struct and separately declaring a new variable `bar` as type `foo`?

Comment: bar is simply a foo object. It is the same as `struct foo {//something};` `foo bar;`

Comment: Related: [How to initialize a struct to 0 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240589/how-to-initialize-a-struct-to-0-in-c/61240590#61240590)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes. `bar.a` and `bar.b` are set to true, but `bar.c` is undefined.  However, certain compilers will set it to false.

See a live example here: [struct demo](http://ideone.com/YFxksN)

According to C++ standard Section 8.5.12:

> if no initialization is performed, an
>   object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value

For primitive built-in data types (**bool**, char, wchar_t, short, int, long, float, double, long double), only **global** variables (all static storage variables) get default value of zero if they are not explicitly initialized.

If you don't really want undefined `bar.c` to start with, you should also initialize it like you did for `bar.a` and `bar.b`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious just updated, sorry I was distracted by other stuff and not with computer.

Comment: It's not "undefined", it is _uninitialized_, meaning it has an _indeterminate value_.

Comment: I think OP meant to say that the _value_ is undefined, not the member.

Answer (score 311):

You don't even need to define a constructor

```
struct foo {
    bool a = true;
    bool b = true;
    bool c;
 } bar;
```

To clarify: these are called brace-or-equal-initializers (because you may also use brace initialization instead of equal sign). This is not only for aggregates: you can use this in normal class definitions. This was added in C++11.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Since August 21, 2011, the `c++` tag means C++11.  People are welcome to say C++98 or C++03 if they want to discuss an old version.  And sometime next year, the bare `c++` tag will change again to mean C++14.

Comment: It's worth noting this immediately makes the type non-POD (verified via `std::is_pod<T>::value`) and so, in that sense, is equivalent to writing a non-default constructor that sets the same values in an initialiser list.

Comment: Actually brace initialization is only allowed when there are no default member initializers in C++11. This limitation is lifted with C++14. ideone uses C++14 but if you use any C++11 compiler that code will fail. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: What if the struct is defined using typedef, like C style? still initializes?

Answer (score 13):

You can do it by using a constructor, like this:

```
struct Date
{
int day;
int month;
int year;

Date()
{
    day=0;
    month=0;
    year=0;
}
};
```

or like this:

```
struct Date
{
int day;
int month;
int year;

Date():day(0),
       month(0),
       year(0){}
};
```

In your case bar.c is undefined,and its value depends on the compiler (while a and b were set to true).

Comment: There is no reason to prefer the first form.  You should use initialization lists.

Comment: @jamesdlin agreed in 99.9% of cases, where the 2nd is vastly preferable for countless reasons. however - just to play devil's advocate! - if rather than `int`s the members were custom classes that had to meet the definition of trivial (e.g. no non-default constructor), that would be a reason to assign in the body instead of constructing in the init list. however, the number of scenarios in which this is useful are, presumably, a tiny minority, so init lists should definitely be the default recommendation - with the rare exceptions being carefullly qualified and justified, unlike here.

Comment: @underscore_d No it wouldn't be such a reason. You can use initialiser lists in all cases except where member variables are interdependent, and that is a violation of 3NF ;-)

Comment: @EJP It very much **can** be a reason; I've needed it several times. I think you're focussing on the parent initialisation, but I'm talking about its members. For member objects whose `default` ctors are inappropriate & standard layout precludes non-`default` constructors, one _must_ perform 'initialisation' another way, be it `operator=` or an init function or whatever. It makes sense to do this 'iniitialisation' in the parent's constructor i.e. assign in its body. `operator=` here is equivalent to in-body assignment of primitives as in the post. Overthinking or tangential maybe, but true ;-)

Comment: @jamesdlin, the first form is valuable for explicitly initializing an array exactly how you want it. Update...or is that possible in an initialization list too?

Comment: @GabrielStaples If you're initializing individual elements of an array, then yes, you would need to do that in a constructor body.  Obviously there are some things that *must* be done in a constructor body.  My earlier comment was specifically talking about the specific examples in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

An explicit default initialization can help:

```
struct foo {
    bool a {};
    bool b {};
    bool c {};
 } bar;
```

Behavior `bool a {}` is same as `bool b = bool();` and return `false`.