# Typedef-ing nonexisting struct in c

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I am currently learning pointers and structs, and I cant understand the following

```
typedef struct at atom;
struct at {
     int element = 5;
     struct at *next;
}
```

how come this code doesn't throw an error?

and when I create an atom using

```
atom x;
printf("%d", x.element);
```

it will print 5.

I don't understand the typedefing of non-existing structure, how does that work?

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct at atom;
```

Here, you are *declaring* a `struct` called `at` and giving it a `typedef` of `atom`. So that is completely valid C.

```
struct at {
     int element = 5;
     struct at *next;
}
```

Here, you are *defining* the struct `at` that you declared earlier.

**NOTE:**

It is important to note that in C, you are not allowed to initialize variables within a struct like you do here:

```
struct at {
     int element = 5; // <---- Illegal in C
     struct at *next;
}
```

**However**, this is perfectly okay in C++ so if you're trying to use C, remove the variable initialization, but if you're working with C++ then it's fine the way it is.

Comment: But initialization of struct members (`int element = 5;`) is not allowed in C.

Comment: @l3x In C you're correct, however you can do this is C++ [**See here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782103/initializing-default-values-in-a-struct)

Answer (score 2):

It's a forward declaration — in C you are permitted to declare that a named thing will exist without giving details about it until later; that's most common used to allow cycles of knowledge; e.g. `struct A` has a pointer to `struct B`, `struct B` has a pointer to `struct C`, and `struct C` has a pointer to `struct A`. In that specific case, as long as you've said that the things are structs then the compiler knows enough about the type to know what an appropriate pointer will look like.

In this case you've declared that there will be a struct called `at` and that you'll want to refer to it as `atom`. If you were to try to declare an `atom` before telling the compiler what `struct at` looks like, that'd be an error. But until then the compiler has enough information to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to place a semicolon

```
typedef struct at atom;
struct at {
     int element = 5;
     struct at *next;
}
^^^^
```

Take into account that it is a C++ code. In C you may not initialize data members of a structure within its definition.

This declaration

```
typedef struct at atom;
```

declares two things. First of all it declares new type `struct at` in the current declarative region. And it declares an alias for this type `atom`

It is not necessary that each declaration would be at the same time a definition.

At first `struct at` is declared and then it is defined

```
struct at {
     int element = 5;
     struct at *next;
};
```

Compare thsi approach for example with functions. Functions also may be several times declared and only one time defined. For example

```
void f();
void f();
//...
void f();

void f() { std::cout << "It is a joke" << std::endl; }
```

The same way a structure may be several times declared but only one time defined.