# Default value of a struct member

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer

*(I'm sure this question has already been answered, I'm just not sure on the right words to use to ask it. If someone would tell me what the correct terminology is that would be awesome!)*

I'm implementing a `HashSet` in C++ for a data structures class, and I have a question about C++ syntax regarding structs. Here is my code:

```
struct HashNode
{
    T value;
    HashNode* next = nullptr;
};
```

Will this code correctly initialize the `next` pointer to `nullptr` when `new HashNode` is called? If not, what is the value of `next` after `new HashNode`?

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782103/initializing-default-values-in-a-struct? See second answer.

Comment: Does it compile? NB These are *initial* values, not 'default' values.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you so much @pingul

Comment: @EJP Yes it does, at least on my machine (C++11 I believe)

Comment: So you're asking whether the compiler produces correct object code for this construction?

Comment: I suppose I am. I'm not really sure what "object code" means.

Comment: You're essentially asking whether the compile does what the code tells it to do. Well it does. Why would you feel the need to confirm that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will this code correctly initialize the next pointer to nullptr when new HashNode is called?

Yes, it will be initialized to `nullptr`. This is [in-class brace-or-equal initializer (default member initializer)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11), it will be used if the member is omitted in member initializer list.

> Through a default member initializer, which is simply a brace or
>   equals initializer included in the member declaration, which is used
>   if the member is omitted in the member initializer list
>
> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the
>   member initialization list in a constructor, the default member
>   initializer is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology!